# Meteor. Make sure user is logged into only one tab?

Tags: meteor

if people log into my Meteor 1.3.1 app from more than one tab/browser they're going to have problems.

So, when a user logs in, I'd like to log them out everywhere else, and park them on a "you logged in somewhere else" page.

I tried a couple things:  Accounts.logoutOtherClients() looked promising, but seems to be broken.  This logs everyone out.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // FF 1 tab, Chrome 2 tabs.
  // FF login -> chrome logs out ok.
  // Chrome login -> FF logs out.  Then Chrome other tab logs in.  Then both Chrome tabs logout.
  Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    console.log(Meteor.loggingIn()); // false.  See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1616
    Accounts.logoutOtherClients();
  });
}
```

Before that I was working on a hand-rolled solution, but it seemed like Meteor.logout() would logout both tabs in the same browser.  The best I could get was `window.location="https://google.com"`

NOTE: The approach below doesn't work if user closes all tabs.  When they re-open app, they don't have a tabToken, so can never login again.

What's the way to do this?

The best way I can think to do this is:

1) At Meteor.start() on the client make a unique tabToken
2) Save token to Session variable on client
3) At login save tabToken to user
4) On client, listen to Meteor.user().profile for tabToken changes.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // Make a unique tabToken at startup.
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    var tabToken = (0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36);  // jshint ignore:line
    Session.set('tabToken', tabToken);
    console.log('startup TabToken ' + Session.get('tabToken'));
  });

  // onLogin, set the active tab to our tabToken
  Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    Meteor.call('setActiveTab', Session.get('tabToken'), function() {
      // When method returns, watch profile for tabToken changes
      console.log('setActiveTab tabToken ' + Session.get('tabToken'));
      console.log('setActiveTab Meteor.user().profile.tabToken ' + Meteor.user().profile.tabToken);

      Tracker.autorun(function (c) {
        // If the tabToken changes to a different token, logout
        if (Meteor.user()) {
          var userTabToken = Meteor.user().profile.tabToken;
          if (userTabToken && !Session.equals('tabToken', userTabToken)) {
            window.location = 'https://google.com';
            // Doesn't work
            // c.stop();
            // Meteor.logout(); // ERROR this logs out all tabs in browser.
            // Router.go('loggedOut');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

// Make a meteor method to set tabToken
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    setActiveTab: function(tabToken) {
      if(!tabToken) throw new Meteor.Error('noTabToken');
      console.log('setActiveTab ' + tabToken);
      if (!Meteor.user()) return;
      Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
        $set: {
          'profile.tabToken': tabToken
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This just seems really kludgy.  Any other suggestions?

Mike

Comment: I know it's not really helping, but you should fix your app. Cross-tabs synchronisation (using html5 localstorage) is a core feature of Meteor accounts. Besides, getting logged out unexpectedly is really bad UX. :(

Comment: Yeah, it's not really helping.  I would have asked that question if it was the answer I needed.  Multiple tabs actually makes a bad UX for my application.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Maybe [Meteor.onConnection()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_onconnection) could help you here? It's called whenever a new DDP connection is created. If each user can only have one active DDP session, you can easily disable the conflicting feature in your app on the client side, and let the user reactivate with one click. This way you won't have to log out your users. (I know, this is not what you asked, sorry for that.)

Comment: Aha!  Brilliant!  That's even better!

Comment: What issues are caused when a user has more than one tab?